# How to keep containers (barrels) from resetting?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I know there are questions here about "where is a safe container to store my items", but I don't feel like making lengthy treks to a "safe" container (eg, Winterhold college dorm room, house in Whiterun).  Personally, I like to store my items in Riverwood's barrels since they're so close to the entrance where I appear when I fast travel.  I have a total of five barrels there that are **heaping full** of items that I have accumulated since the very beginning of my quest.  Just today, I went back to drop off a bunch of loot when I realized the barrels were all reset to salt piles and apples.  I lost a lot of game progress as I reloaded save after save until I found the one that had all my accumulated items.  There is no way I am going to relocate all this stuff.  *No way at all*.  That would take hours (not in game time).

Is there some mod or cheat that can keep containers from resetting?  That's all I am interested in.  *Keeping containers from resetting*.  I have *zero* (0) interest in moving this stuff to another location.

**Edit:** Some research has shown me that these containers reset after a given period of time has gone by without you entering the area the container is in.  Now that I think about it, I served a jail sentence in Markarth.  Could that jail sentence have spanned the time period that caused the barrels in Riverwood to reset?

**Update:** It was a combination of the passing of time during my jail sentence and the game time spent after the fact while I was oblivious to barrels resetting.  To test this, I waited far outside Riverwood for 48 hours.  Barrels still had my items.  I reloaded the game and served my jail sentence (it was the 27th of Evening Star when I went in, 4th of Morning Star when I got out).  Went back to Riverwood and the barrels were still full.  Reloaded game in Markarth, waited 48 hours, then served my jail sentence.  Went back to Riverwood and the barrels were reset!

Comment: I haven't seen any mods to that effect, but if you're that adamant about absolutely 100% *not* moving things you may have to accept the only alternative - losing your stuff when the containers reset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way to keep containers from resetting is to personally enter the cell they're located at every X days, where X is the respawn period of the cell, sans mods. I doubt there's a mod that targets those particular barrels, but if you're determined to use them, the [Creation Kit](http://www.creationkit.com/) allows you to [change the properties of containers](http://www.creationkit.com/Container).

A much simpler solution would be to use the console command "player.modav carryweight 1000000" to give yourself enough inventory capacity to carry all the things, could also be handy for relocating the stash to a safe container.

Comment: The carry weight console cheat will come in handy in the event I find some convenient, safe containers.  As far as the respawn period, I come back to my barrels constantly and have been doing so since the start of the game.  The only thing I can think of is that my jail sentence in Markarth allowed enough game time to pass without me being in the containers' "cells".

Comment: I'm sure you can find a house mod that features convenient storage.

Comment: See update to my question for interesting test case results.

Comment: That's interesting, but jail time is not different from regular in-game time for purposes of cell respawning.

Comment: That's why I did that experiment.  I wanted to test if the time period was in game time or actual play hours.  It turns out that it's game time, so the in-game passage of time is the culprit here.  I marked yours as the answer since it's true that you need to visit your containers before the respawn period occurs.

Comment: OP here reporting in that I finally got around to using the creation kit to add extra non-respawning barrels in Riverwood.  After adding some items to these barrels, fast traveling far away, and waiting over 10 days, I returned to find that the vanilla barrels had been reset while the contents of my custom barrels remained.  Good call on the creation kit.

Comment: Glad to hear that.